# MySQL SELECT last few days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was playing with MYSQL and I know there's a limit command that shows a certain amount of results, but i was wondering if MySQL alone can show only the last 3 days or something. Just wondering.

**Update:**
I used NOW() to store times.

Comment: @Doug, please give us a bit more information.  How do your record reckon time DATETIMEs, DATEs, TIMESTAMPs, epoch timestamps, etc.?  Do you want the last three days from now (CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAYS) or from the most recent record?  Etc.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Use for a date three days ago:

```
WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY);
```

Check the [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) documentation.

Or you can use:

```
WHERE t.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

Comment: "WHERE t.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )" should be sufficient

Comment: VERY INTERESTING! I tried running that with DATE_ADD and it kept failing because of syntax. However, it worked without DATE_ADD, so I only used `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY`. Why is that?

Comment: I was running it through phpmyadmin if that makes a difference.

Comment: i find `BETWEEN (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND CURDATE()` to be nice also. is it internally different?

Comment: DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY) IS FASTER

Comment: Its supposed to be WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3, DAY); ( complete with commas) to pass syntax checks

Comment: You can use current_timestamp() instead of CURDATE() if your date field is a timestamp and not a date you want a more specific/accurate comparison.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this in your MySQL WHERE clause to return records that were created within the last 7 days/week:

`created >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 day)`

Also use NOW() in the subtraction to give hh:mm:ss resolution. So to return records created exactly (to the second) within the last 24hrs, you could do:

`created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 day)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to do that.

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(thefield) < 259200
```

Comment: @Turnor, caution, days do not always consist of 86,400 seconds, what with leap seconds and daylight savings.

Comment: True. But it's rare that you'd need that level of precision, and it didn't sound like the original question did.

Comment: @pilcrow Keeping that in mind, how would you approach the question then?

Comment: @JeremyVisser, I'd subtract `INTERVAL 3 DAY`, as in [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1713381/132382).

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),pickup_date) AS noofday 
FROM cir_order 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),pickup_date)>2;
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM cir_order 
WHERE cir_order.`cir_date` >= DATE_ADD( CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY )
```

Answer (score -3):

`WHERE t.date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL '-3' DAY);`

use quotes on the -3 value