# SQL Items within the Last Day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my code, I am trying to find items in an activities table that are within the last day. This query is not returning any results, are there any problems with it? Is there a better query?

```
$curday = time() - (24*3600);
$query = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE userid = '$userid' AND  'timestamp' > '$curday'";
```

Comment: It's already hooked up to it, but for the record it is 'fitdb' and it is using MySQL.

Comment: I meant the type of the DB (Oracle etc.)

Comment: I am not sure. It is using PHPMyAdmin with MySQL. Does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

There are two choices here, you can get and format the date through PHP or use SQL language to do it. I prefer to do it within the SQL, it also allows me to use the same query in a MySQL client.

This question is essentially the same thing: [MySQL SELECT last few days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713056/mysql-select-last-few-days)

This would be the new query:
`$query = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE userid = '$userid' AND  'timestamp' > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)";`

Answer (score 1):

you can try with unix function 'mktime' to get value of yesterday ..
as

```
$curday = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y"));
```

[for reference](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp)

if your database will mysql only then you can extract yesterday in sql itself..

```
SELECT * FROM activities 
WHERE userid = '$userid' 
AND  timestamp >  DATE_SUB(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

one more thing if timestamp is your column name don't put this column inside single quote ..

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is DATE_SUB. This can be used as follows

```
SELECT * FROM activities 
WHERE userid = '$userid' 
AND  timestamp > date_sub(current_date, interval 1 day)
```

This way you don't need to work with current date in PHP

Answer (score -2):

in Informix it would be (TODAY - 1) if the column is type DATE