# Mysql: results from last seven days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

It's my first time creating a website with PHP and MySQL. How do I query the results of a Mysql search to display only the results from the last 7 days?

The columns in my database are:

```
Id
Name
Date
Mensage
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: *"We do not write your code for you."* -- but still you wrote `:D`

Comment: I do my best to teach in all of its forms. :)

Comment: Notice: `mysql()*` is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, it is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

 I personally prefer `PDO` over `MYSQLI` due to named parameter support.

Comment: Ok... what have you tried?

Comment: @JohnConde normally I would agree with you, but since this is the user's first time posting and what he's asking is very precise/clear, lets cut Yan some slack this time. He's only asking for a couple of lines after all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT last few days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713056/mysql-select-last-few-days)

Answer (score 7):

There's a few ways to do this. Here's one.

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE `date` > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

And another:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE DATEDIFF(`date`, CURRENT_DATE) < 7
```

FYI, you should not name your columns using [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). It's a bad idea and can only cause problems for you.

Comment: Although it is bad practice, You can use reserved words if you enclose them via a " ` "

Comment: even `date` is not wrap with backtick, it will still work because mysql allows it (*it is one of the reserved keywords that are allowed to be used even without backtick*).

Comment: @JohnConde . . . The first version is much better because the query plan can make use of an index on `date`.

Comment: here you can see the error im getting [link]http://igrejanavegantes.com.br/testes/comentarios.php

Comment: Please do not put PHP code in your comment. Create a new question for this problem @YanCustodio

Comment: @YanCustodio the syntax of a link is: [link](URL goes here)

Answer (score 0):

Get the last 7 days date

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

Get the current

```
SELECT NOW();
```

There is complete query example by combine two above parts

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_created` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW();
```

By use this query you could get data from database than execute with php mysql_query and mysql_result function