# Limit MySQL Results to X Days

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field in my table called date and it stores via the NOW() function the date the entry was added.

I need to query the database to find entries within the last 30 days only.

Is this possible in a single query?

Comment: Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13997176/1415724 and A: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997357/1415724 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14799618/1415724 as found under **"Related" >>>**

Comment: .. your_date < NOW() + interval 30 day ..

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616869/get-from-database-but-only-last-30-days

Comment: ^-- Q: => A: => http://stackoverflow.com/a/9616907/1415724

Comment: Another duplicate here: [MySQL Query - Records between Today and Last 30 Days](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2041575/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Create a time window and you can limit by that date

```
$time = time() - (86400 * 30); // 86400 seconds in one day
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE datefield > "' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time) . '"';
```

That should yield you records within the last 30 days

Comment: why not use the built in mysql functions?

Comment: I've always shifted my processing to PHP because the database tends to be the choke point in processing. If this is just a one-off thing it probably doesn't matter. But feel free to post the MySQL answer