# Manipulate a string as a date with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am working with a MySQL table which has entries like the following for the timestamp `2016-12-28T21:42:53.000-04:00` provided as a `CHAR` field.
One of the tasks I need to do is to retrieve all the records for the current date.

Right now what I am doing is getting the current date into a `php` variable `($date)` in the same format as the one in the `MySQL` table. `ie 2016-12-28` and use a `LIKE` statement to find all the records matching it.

The problem comes when I need to find all the records for the last 10 days for example.

Is there anyway to convert that field into a valid date one which I can use for more complex queries like find the last 10 days, etc?

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just convert it to a date.  One method is:

```
select date(left(field, 10))
```

I should add that this will work just as well in a `where` clause:

```
where date(left(field, 10)) >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 day)
```

But . . . using functions on columns precludes the use of indexes.  In this case, you have a good date format, so you could do:

```
where field >= date_format(date_sub(curdate(), interval 10 day), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This version can take advantage of an index on `field`.

All that said . . . storing fields using the proper type is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon!

Comment: For anyone else finding this, acording to the answer above I then would do the following to find the previous 10 days `select date(left(date_created, 10)) FROM orders WHERE date(left(date_created, 10)) >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -10 DAY)` [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713056/mysql-select-last-few-days)