# Count number of rows then update - Php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to count the rows from a table with date timestamp and then update with total rows created in the last 24 hours:

Here is function code

```
function limitexchnage($eid) {
  global $db;
  $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM exchanges WHERE uid='$eid' and created less than 24 hour ");
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET maxechange='$query->num_rows' WHERE id='$eid'");
   }  }
```

I need someone to help me finds timestamps in the last 24 hours and fix this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT last few days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713056/mysql-select-last-few-days)

Comment: not the same , check again

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition in your where clause `WHERE (Date_Time = getdate())`

Comment: i don't understand :(

Comment: find equivalent of getDate() in php that returns you today's date.

Comment: and created less than 24 hour , this is not correct 

created is a coulumn 

maxechange='$query->num_rows' also this not correct 

need somone understand more

Comment: i set $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM exchanges WHERE uid='$eid' and created>=date_sub(now(), 24 hours"); and not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function limitexchnage() {
global $db;
$check = $db->query("SELECT * FROM exchanges WHERE `created` > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - 86400) AND `uid` = '$eid'");
        $update = $db->query("UPDATE users SET maxechange='$check->num_rows' WHERE id='$eid'"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
"SELECT * FROM exchanges WHERE uid='$eid' and date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);"
```

same condition in update too.
this returns date with value within last 24 hrs

Answer (score 0):

You can actually combine these into a single query:

```
function limitexchnage($eid) {
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("UPDATE users SET maxechange=(SELECT COUNT(uid) FROM exchanges WHERE uid='$eid' AND created < NOW() AND created > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) WHERE id='$eid'");
}
```

You should swap the `COUNT(uid)` part to use the primary index of `exchanges` table. Remember to escape/sanitize `$eid` when using directly in the query!